# Handling dates in pentaho kettle

Tags: date, pentaho, kettle

I am new to pentaho, and have got a requirement as, i have a flat file that have date column having dates as 01-Jan-1999 , 02-Mar-1987 etc. i want the result in an another flatfile performing the transformation that make dates as follows:
01-01-1999,02-03-1987 (dd-mm-yyyy).
have tried using calculator and select values but nothing helped.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use a Select-Values step (which can do what you need to do) when Text-File-Output already can [format a date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The date value has nothing to do with its format.

When you read in the flat file, you need to specify the format dd-MMM-yyyy to convert a String into a Date. When you write out to a file, you need to specify the format dd-mm-yyyy to convert a Date to a String.

Now, in your case, you may have a issue because months are in French. You can change the Metadata with a Select Value specifying the Locale as fr_FR.